# How would I compute exactly 30 days into the past with Python (down to the minute)?

Tags: python, datetime, date, time

In Python, I'm attempting to retrieve the date/time that is exactly 30 days (30*24hrs) into the past. At present, I'm simply doing:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(-30)
```

Which returns a datetime object, but with no time data:

```
>>> start_date.year
2009
>>> start_date.hour
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You want to use a `datetime` object instead of just a `date` object:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(30)
```

`date` just stores a date and `time` just a time. `datetime` is a date with a time.

Comment: Also works for me:  `datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)`