# How to count frequency last month in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

i have a dataframe like this :

| customer_id | trx_date | trx_amount | last_trx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CS5295 | 2013-02-11 | 35 | 2014-11-25 |
| CS5295 | 2014-11-25 | 54 | 2014-11-25 |
| CS5295 | 2013-05-22 | 36 | 2014-11-25 |
| CS5295 | 2012-12-24 | 36 | 2014-11-25 |
| CS5295 | 2013-03-22 | 43 | 2014-11-25 |
| CS5295 | 2013-02-11 | 25 | 2014-11-25 |

how can i count the **trx_amount**,  from last month in **last_trx**, and **customer_id** as a parameter?

Expected Output :

| customer_id | trx_times |
| --- | --- |
| CS5295 | 1 |

from the **last month** of the date in **last_trx**, 2014-11-25

counting how many times did **customer_id** make a trx from **2014-10-25** to **2014-11-25**

Comment: Please post expected output.

Comment: done, for the example output. thanks

Comment: How does that make sense?  sum(trx_amount) is 229, count(trx_amount) is 6.  Where do you get 12?

Comment: that's just some example, but that should be 1 because last month from the last_trx only did 1 trx, from 2014 - 10 - 25 to 2014 - 11 - 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity I will call the DataFrame `transact_df` and assume it is a pandas dataframe. Additionally, the `"last_trx"` column is assumed be already be in the dataframe.

1. Convert the columns to DateTime if not already done:
   [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)
2. Identify all rows that qualify: [How would I compute exactly 30 days into the past with Python (down to the minute)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703907/how-would-i-compute-exactly-30-days-into-the-past-with-python-down-to-the-minut)

```
valid_transacts_df = transact_df.loc[(transact_df['trans_date'] 
                                     > transact_df['last_trx'] - datetime.timedelta(30))]
```

3. Count/sum the values you want:

```
# Number of transactions in the last 30 days
trx_times = len(valid_transacts_df)

# Sum of transactions in the last 30 days
total_amount = sum(valid_transacts_df['trx_amount'])
```

If necessary, you can combine steps 2 & 3 to shorten your code.

Comment: Thanks!, not the exact result what im looking for, but definitely help alot. with a little change it works perfectly